# Applying function on merge

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, merge, min, concatenation

I have two dataframes. Snippets are pasted below

Employee

[image]

Project

[image]

Both the dataframes have common columns "Level" and "skill" on which i need to merge the "EmployeeID"  column of Employee dataframe to Project dataframe. But the problem is i need to add those EmployeeID to Project whose CostToCompany is the lowest. How can i do that?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can ,`drop_duplicates` select the min cost one

```
Employee=Employee.sort_values(['Level','skill','CostToCompany']).drop_duplicates(['Level','skill','Rating'],keep='first')
```

Then,

```
Project1=pd.merge(Project,Employee['Level','skill','Employee ID'].on='cols')
```

Or you can using your result doing :

```
Project1.sort_values(['Level','skill','CostToCompany']).drop_duplicates(['Level','skill','Rating'],keep='first')
```

Comment: My Project dataframe has 10 rows. So eventually  on merging i should have 10 rows but i am getting 20 rows . Also same set of skill and Level set is repeating with different EmployeeID

Comment: `Project1=pd.merge(Project,Employee['Level','skill','Rating'].on='cols',how='left')`, make sure you drop duplicated as what I am doing in the first line

Comment: I think  i should not use 'Rating' on drop_duplicates. Then it gives me 10 rows

Comment: @Biswa yeah you are right , it is hard for writing the code without the data, so please do not show picture next time dude ~ :-)

Comment: Thanks dude. will take note of that. Your code worked

Comment: @Biswa yw~ :-) Nice day